# How to pass variable values dynamically in pandas sql query

Tags: python, pandas, prepared-statement

How to pass variable parameters dynamically

```
order = 10100

status = 'Shipped'

df1 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT  * from orders where orderNumber =""" +  
str(10100) + """ and status = """ + 'status' +"""  order by orderNumber """,cnx)
```

TypeError: must be str, not int

getting above error although i converted to strings any idea?

is there any alternative wy to pass the parameters?

Comment: Can you print `orders.dtypes`?

Comment: orderNumber        int64
orderDate         object
requiredDate      object
shippedDate       object
status            object
comments          object
customerNumber     int64

Comment: Not sure then, try unutbu's answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use parametrized sql by supplying the arguments via the [`params` keyword argument](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html). The proper quotation of arguments will be done for you by the database adapter and the code will be less vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) attacks. (See [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) for an example of the kind of trouble improperly quoted, non-parametrized sql can get you into.)

```
order = 10100

status = 'Shipped'

sql = """SELECT  * from orders where orderNumber = ?
         and status = ? order by orderNumber"""
df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnx, params=[order, status])
```

The `?`s in `sql` are [parameter markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle). They get replaced with properly quoted values from `params`. Note that the proper parameter marker depends on the database adapter you are using. For example, `MySQLdb` and `psycopg2` uses `%s`, while `sqlite3`,  and `oursql` uses `?`.

Comment: Thanks..i am working with Teradata will it work?  is there any limit in the parameters pass in the query or we can pass multiple parameters?

Comment: I expect it should work though I'm not familiar with Teradata. The best way is to try and see.

Comment: Thanks will check on this tomorrow in office

Comment: so here we no need to specify whether its string or integer it will automatically picks based on the initialization?

Comment: The database adapter does the quoting for you, based on the value of the parameter and the table schema.

Comment: Thanks it worked. how to use the same parameter multiple times instead of writing multiple times?

Comment: order = 10100

status = 'Shipped'

date = '2003-01-13'

sql = """SELECT  * from orders where orderNumber = %s
         and status = %s and requiredDate = %s and  shippedDate = %s"""
df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnx, params=[order, status,date,date])

Comment: here date is passing twice is there any way to reduce this?

Comment: If your database adapter accepts pyformat placemarkers, then you could use
`sql = """SELECT * from orders where orderNumber = %(order)s and status = %(status)s and requiredDate = %(date)s and shippedDate = %(date)s"""` with `df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnx, params={'order':order, 'status':status, 'date':date})`. Or you could keep your `sql` the same and use `params=[order, status] + [date]*2`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..in second option    params=[order, status] + [date]*2 here the sequence of parmeter order matters?

Comment: Yes, if you use a list the order matters.

Answer (score 3):

```
IN MYSQL ::

order = 10100

status = 'Shipped'
sql = """SELECT  * from orders where orderNumber = %s
         and status = %s order by orderNumber"""
df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnx, params=[order, status])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think of your query as a string, you can replace your variable with the actual value of that variable using string formatting first, and then use it in your SQL query.

```
order = 10100
status = 'Shipped'

query1 = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orderNumber = " + str(order) + " AND status = " + status + " ORDER BY orderNumber"

df1 = pandasql.sqldf(query1, locals())
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**